# how to autoclick with xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to autoclick with full xpath but nothing happens where is the problem.

thanks a lot

here is the code:

```
browser.get("https://www.gazzetta.gr/")
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/header/div/div[2]/nav/ul[2]/li[6]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are cookies button and a pop, you need to click on that beforehand, in order to interact with `ΠΡΟΓΡΑΜΜΑ TV` link

You can try below code :

```
browser.maximize_window()
browser.implicitly_wait(30)
browser.get("https://www.gazzetta.gr/")
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='ΠΕΡΙΣΣΟΤΕΡΕΣ ΕΠΙΛΟΓΕΣ']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//button[@aria-label='ΑΠΟΘΗΚΕΥΣΗ ΚΑΙ ΕΞΟΔΟΣ'])[2]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "ΠΡΟΓΡΑΜΜΑ TV"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```